# Java inner class syntax / how to use

Tags: java, scope, inner-classes

//** SOLVED **//

I found out (as 2 people mentioned - that it is possible to access content from inner classes to outer classes. I must have done something else wrong, since I could not access it

//** SOLVED **//

I'm using a Phillips Hue API (http://www.developers.meethue.com/documentation/java-sdk-getting-started)
And it comes with some listeners, but i don't think i've seen structure like this in java before...

I don't want an answer on how to use this API - just in general, how this syntax of listeners works.

In the fields area, the listener with method is defined:

```
public class someClass {
    private int someVariable;
    private PHSDKListener listener = new PHSDKListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBlablabla(Object something) {
            // how do i do stuff to an someClass object from here??
        }
    };
    public someClass() {
        // constructor
    }
    private void someMehtod() {
        // a standard method that i am used to.
    }
}
```

My question: This listener-method `onBlablabla` is like not a part of the class it is within - it cannot access variables and methods in the class - so how do I use this listener-method, when I can't access anything/store any data in the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to judge what exactly you are trying to do, but generally from inside an inner class, you can access member variables and methods of the outer class (including private ones) directly using their names or, if you want to be more specific, using `parentClass.this` notation, so in your case:

```
Public class someClass {
    private int someVariable;
    private PHSDKListener listener = new PHSDKListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBlablabla(Object something) {
            int localVar1 = someVariable; //this will work
            int localVar2 = someClass.this.someVariable; //this will also work
        }
    };
    public someClass() {
        // constructor
    }
    private void someMehtod() {
        // a standard method that i am used to.
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, now i can. I must have done something else wrong, since i could not acces it before. Sorry for wasting your time -.- but thanks for answering. And thanks for noticing me, that this is called an "inner class".

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure you can access the outer class. For example it should be no problem calling someMethod() out of onBlablabla()...

Comment: It is not possible. I can only access static methods and variables like if the onBlablabla is in another class.

Comment: @CasperTraberg-Larsen Did you try it?  I am fairly sure it's possible.

Comment: @peez80 Well, now i can. I must have done something else wrong, since i could not acces it before. Sorry for wasting your time -.- but thanks for answering.